# How to say "one trick left", "one card left", "something more up my sleeve"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What can you say when you have used many possibilities, but there is still one available solution that people are not usually expecting?

In PIV/Vortaro.net, there is

> truk/o
>
> - 1 Artifiko uzata en filmado, por doni la aspekton de realeco
>   al dekoracio ks.
> - 2 (f) Ĉia lertaĵo aŭ artifiko.

but I am not sure if this word is suited, because here the "trick" is not a way to hide truth nor to give the impression of truth.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne konas la anglan esprimon, sed ĉu *Restas unu truko* ne esprimus la saman?

Comment: La difino de "truko" laŭ Reta-Vortaro ne ŝajnas kongrui "KIN Artifiko, kiu iluzias al la spektantoj: kiam mi disŝiris ilin kaj rekunmetis ilin, tio estis nur mantruko [1]."

Comment: Tio estas la malnova difino. PIV diras ankaŭ: Ĉia lertaĵo aŭ artifiko.

Comment: Sxajnas al mi iom strange ke ReVo indikas ke la difino estas por kinarto, cxar la ekzemplo estas de Sorcxisto de Oz, kaj ne temas pri kinajxo. Mi kredas ke ili prenis tiun ideon de la difino en PIV -- sed vere indas atenti kiel la homoj efektive uzas la vorton. Mi auxdis franclingvanojn kiuj (miaopinie) misuzas la vorton - kaj foje oni plendas ke PIV enhavas tro da franca influo. Estu iel ajn, se vi ne volas uzi la vorton "truko", kial ne "artifiko"?

Answer (score 1):

I also am not familiar with the expression, and Google wasn't much help. I'm reminded, however, of expressions with "up one's sleeve".

- *Mi havas ankoraŭ ion en la maniko.*

Are you translating a story that has this expression in it?

This strikes me as a very specific (and potentially culturally dependent) phrase to want to translate. If you want to say "there is still one available solution that people are not usually expecting", why not just say "there is still one available solution that people are not expecting"?

- *Ankoraŭ restas unu eblo.*
- *Mi ne elĉerpis la eblajn solvojn.*
- *Mi ne venis al la fino de mia latino.*

Regarding the word *truko* - I would be mindful of national language influence in our dictionaries - especially of influence from French.

Comment: I have edited the question to precise my thoughts

Comment: Dankon. Responde, mi aldonis "Ankoraŭ io en la maniko."

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for may be *atuto* (a trump card, if you will pardon the expression) or *ruzaĵo* (a ruse).

- *Ankoraŭ restas atuto enmanike.*
- *Mia provizo de ruzo ankoraŭ ne malplenas.*

The words *rimedo, solvo* are neutral; *elturniĝilo* suggests a desperate wriggle; *lertaĵo* is a piece of cleverness; *manovro* is quasi-military. (*Ruzo* can mean artfulness or an individual ruse.)